# Dystopian books series in which the protagonists are a girl and boy escaping a controlled society

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult, dystopia

The books themselves weren't incredibly long. There were three books in the series when I read them. I had read them in early 2000's/2010's - I remember they had something to do with the "shadows" as the kids called them.

- The story is told from the perspective of multiple people (two were the main perspectives).
- The main protagonist was a boy who lived in an isolated prison-like tower and has some time-manipulation power.
- Another protagonist was a girl who lived with her parents and was conflicted about a coming-of-age ceremony.
- The antagonist is some president/overseer that controlled society through a type of pill they take starting at ~10 years old (I think); they had some checks in school to make sure they were taking it.
- It is a dystopic novel.
- The boy got older the more he used his power.
- Because they weren't under the control of the medication and had these powers, they were a threat to the system currently in place.

I vaguely remember two of the covers; one was a greenish/blue with a stormy tower in the back - the other was a hazy blue through some trees.